# pushing whole react folder to github

Tags: reactjs, git, github

Im new with git stuff. I wanted to push my react project made with "create-react-app" into github and make it work with github pages. So i followed some tutorial and it basically worked so i could preview it on a github page. But now i want to push whole folder of my react project instead of only files. To make it working i deleted .git folder inside my app folder and initialized one outside. I ended up pushing it to my github repo but i cannot live preview my site for some reason.

https://github.com/Adrian397/react_projects - here is how it looks like (there is main folder in master branch)

This is how my package.json looks like.
I dont know if the "homepage" is written properly but i tried to change it to "homepage": "http://Adrian397.github.io/react_projects/expenses" (react_projects is my whole repo and expenses is my folder that i pushed into github) but still did not work.
[image]

Is there any other way to do it because it is kinda weird if i had to create a new repository for every react project instead of having them separeted in one global repository?

Comment: Please replace the image with the text from your file

Comment: Note: Git does not push *folders*. Git pushes *commits*. A commit contains files (not folders): the files may have names that imply the OS has to *make* a folder, but it just contains the files. The files that go in the new commit are determined by the set of files you have had Git put into Git's index aka staging area.